# How to create a list such that each option is a list in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, html-select

I want to create a list in which each option is a list itself, but when I try [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/8w9RF1oFtj0czMnXKL9v?p=preview), the select tag ends it prematurely. Can this be done at all in AngularJS 1.3?

```
<body ng-app="">
  <select placeHolder="This">
    <option>A place-holder!</option>
    <option>
      <select>
        <option>A place-holder!</option>
      </select>
    </option>
    <option>Greetings!</option>
  </select>
</body>
```

Something like this, using `optgroup` creates a sub-group of option rather than a new list.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a standard HTML component. You'll need a JS library that implements it. One I could find is [selectivity.js](https://arendjr.github.io/selectivity/) but you would have to write a directive to integrate it with your angular app.

```
$('#select-with-sublist').selectivity({
    allowClear: true,
    items: [{
        id: 'a',
        text: 'A',
        submenu: {
            items: [
                { id: 'a1', text: 'A1' },
                { id: 'a2', text: 'A2' },
                { id: 'a3', text: 'A3' }
            ]
        }
    }, {
        id: 'b',
        text: 'B',
        submenu: {
            items: [
                { id: 'b1', text: 'B1' },
                { id: 'b2', text: 'B2' }
            ]
        }
    }],
    placeholder: 'Select',
    showSearchInputInDropdown: false
});
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/LukaszWiktor/ge64o2ym/

Answer (score 1):

Use `<optgroup>` instead of the inner select.

```
<body ng-app="">
  <select placeHolder="This">
    <option>A place-holder!</option>
    <optgroup label="Inner list">
        <option>A place-holder!</option>
        <option>A place-holder!</option>
    </optgroup>
    <option>Greetings!</option>
  </select>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using [this](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/multi-level-dropdown-menu-bs3) example, its a Multi level drop-down menu in Bootstrap 3. Its better to use this since its more flexible. not restricted to two levels only.